# Postgresql fails to start on Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS

Tags: 10.04, postgresql

I installed postgresql 9.2 from `add-apt-repository ppa:pitti/postgresql` using `apt-get install postgresql-9.2`

At the end of the install and every time I try to launch postgresql by using the following command

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

or

```
service postgresql start
```

I get this error:

```
Error: could not exec /usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/pg_ctl    
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.2/main -l 
/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.2-main.log -s -o  -c 
config_file="/etc/postgresql/9.2/main/postgresql.conf" :
                                                                    [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing postgresql-9.2 (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
postgresql-9.2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried everything found here: [How to thoroughly purge and reinstall postgresql on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748607/how-to-thoroughly-purge-and-reinstall-postgresql-on-ubuntu) and here: [Eliminating non working postgresql installations on ubuntu 10-04 and starting af](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874754/eliminating-non-working-postgresql-installations-on-ubuntu-10-04-and-starting-af).

I have also done

```
dpkg -P --force-remove-reinstreq postgresql-client-9.2
```

in my attempt to remove everything postgres related from my server.

After removing postgresql I have used

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep postg
```

To be sure there is nothing left and I can do a clean install.

I have also made sure that the files and folders mentioned in the error message have the right permissions. The `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.2-main.log` file is empty.
I have tried installing every postgresql version from 8.3 to 9.2 and I get the same error on every time. I once managed to compile postgresql from the source provided on their website but then I encountered weird errors with psycopg2 so I figured I'd install postgresql this way and avoid those errors. Also when I type `apt-get install postgresql` it by default tries to install the 8.3 version even when I can find the package by typing  `apt-get install postgresql-9.2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question. I had a Zend installation on my server that interfered with the installation process and caused the error. Since I don't need Zend, I removed it and made sure anything Zend related was removed, by typing:

```
"rm -r /usr/local/zend"
```

after which Postgresql installed and started smoothly. I can't recommend this solution if you need your Zend but for me it worked. I hope this will help people in a similar situation.